# Android :: Camera widget example

Tags: android, android-widget, android-camera

I have been looking for a widget that contain a camera inside without opening the camera app itself.

here is the only example i found:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOJF4eZjzhU

Any help or advice is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `SurfaceView` as described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html).